# Angular MIME issues in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm running into an issue with Angular where if I `ng serve` and deploy on localhost, the page loads fine. However if I use `ng build` and deploy remotely, I then get a MIME error,

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

This only occurs on Edge, but is still a notable issue. The only differing factor I can find is when viewing the compiled source code, the local deployment has the following data in its HTML document,

```
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
```

Where the remote deployment has this,

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
```

I'd think the solution would be to deploy with `runtime.js` rather than `runtime-es2015.js`, but I'm unclear on how to modify those parameters. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I'd check if the "-es2015.js" files exist on the server. If not, deploy them (they're for browsers that can't handle modern JavaScript, so you need both sets of files). The server is probably returning an HTML 404 page.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I checked, they are. I'm able to view the es2015 file online. However, the actual webpage that runs the script isn't loading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're using a subfolder for the deployed app e.g. `www.example.com/appfolder/`

If that's the case the you need to set the `base-href` during the build process: `ng build --prod --base-href appfolder`

Comment: Not the case unfortunately, it's simply www.url.com. There is no subfolder in the domain.